# Validate login form in $.get and submit only if success

Tags: jquery, form-submit, getjson

I need to build web app that shows data from api used by android app, which is json formatted response.
I have login form and following js code:

```
$('#loginForm').submit(function(e) { 
  var username = $('#username').val();
  var password = $('#password').val();

  $.get( "http://myurl/?u="+username+"&p="+password+"", function( data ) {
    if (data == null) { //wrong username or password
      ...
      e.preventDefault();
    } else { 
      // everything is correct, here i want to submit form and pass json data
    }
    })
    .fail(function() { 
      // url's not correct
      ...
      e.preventDefault();
    });

    //e.preventDefault(); 
});
```

The problem is that e.preventDefault(); never occur. I realize that the problem is in $.get(); but i have no other idea of how to validate username and password, since I have to check what api returns, and then submit form and pass parameters to index page.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following approach, cancel the submission by default and if everything is fine, resume the submit event.

```
$('#loginForm').submit(function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault(); //cancel by default
    var $that = $(this); // get form reference 

    var username = $('#username').val();
    var password = $('#password').val();


   $.get( "http://myurl/?u="+username+"&p="+password+"", function( data )      {
       if (data == null) { //wrong username or password
           // show alert with error

       } else { 
         // everything is correct, just submit the form
         // we use $that because $(this) is pointing to something else
         $that.submit();
       }
    }).fail(function() { 
       // url's not correct...
       e.preventDefault(); 
    });
});
```